# Writing down the Vedas

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, vedas

In Mackenzie Brown's paper titled ***Purāṇa as Scripture***, we see a reference wherein it says that,

*Mahabharata, as well as the ancient Smriti writer Vṛddha Gautama(of the Dharmaśāstra) proclaims, "Veda-sellers and those who dishonor the Vedas and also those who write down the Vedas shall go to hell."*

My questions are as follows:

```
1) Which verses of the Mahabharata expressly prohibit the writing down of Vedas?
2) Was the concept of 'Writing' elucidated or mentioned in the Śruti?
```

Comment: Agree with Keshav. There is no mention in Sruti.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's from [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a023.htm) of the Anushasana Parva of the Mahabharata:

> They who sell the Vedas, they who find fault with the Vedas, and they who reduce the Vedas into writing, have all to sink in hell.

And as far as I know, the Vedas never discuss writing.   A quick Google search of the English translations of the Vedas given at http://sacred-texts.com confirms my understanding.

Comment: What keywords did you search for in the Vedas?